# When implementing INotifyPropertyChanged, do navigation properties need to implement it too?

Tags: c#, inotifypropertychanged

When implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` (using Prisim) the code below makes sense, you'd want to know when a property changes.

```
[DisplayName("Media Type Id"), Display(Name = "Media Type Id")]
public int MediaTypeId
{
    get { return this._MediaTypeId; }
    set { this.SetProperty(ref this._MediaTypeId, value); }
}
private int _MediaTypeId;
```

But im a but confused when it comes to navigation properties.

Do I implement it? To me this would make sense if i was to do something like `artist.Album = new Album();`
But what if only needed to change a property like `artist.Album.name = "NEW_NAME"` (assuming `Album.name` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`)
Would the code below still be necessary?

```
[DisplayName("Album"), Display(Name = "Album")]
public Album Album
{
    get { return this._Album; }
    set { this.SetProperty(ref this._Album, value); }
}
private Album _Album;
```

Or will this work just as well

```
public virtual Album Album { get; set; }
```

Same for navigation collections.

```
[DisplayName("Playlists"), Display(Name = "Playlists")]
public ICollection<Playlist> Playlists
{
    get { return this._Playlists; }
    set { this.SetProperty(ref this._Playlists, value); }
}
private ICollection<Playlist> _Playlists
```

Or

```
public virtual ICollection<Playlist> Playlists { get; set; }
```

Comment: It maybe just me, but it seems weird that you are pushing prism down to your entities. are you using your entities as your viewmodals?

Comment: using it for code gen, not for actual production code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you understand, you implement INotifyPropertyChanged (INPC) in order for the UI to update when a property on the model changes. So in your case, if you have something that is data binding to the Album property, it must implement INPC if there is a chance that it might change. Instead of using regular collection, you have a class called ObservableCollection that already implements INPC for you so you don't have to.

Comment: so for collections, `public virtual ObservableCollection <Playlist> Playlists { get; set; }` would be enough and for `Album `, its only necessary if something is binding to the `Album ` object (cant think of a use), not the properties of the object, correct?

Comment: yep, something like that. (for the Album, you could theoretically have a custom control that binds to the whole album, not just a property, in which case it might need to implement INPC)